# How do I get "Tasks" in my list of calendars?

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar, google-tasks

I am the administrator of a Google Apps domain. On at least four accounts in my domain, one of which is my own, (and on any new accounts that I create) the **Tasks** calendar is not in the list of calendars.

When I go to **Settings** → **Calendars**, I don't see a **Tasks** calendar anywhere on the page.

Tasks work fine in Gmail, but I would like to see tasks with a due date on my calendar. I have found many Google help articles that mention the **Tasks** calendar, but I cannot find any help for when that calendar does not exist.

How do I add the **Tasks** calendar to my list of calendars?

I have the free subscription to Google Apps, so I have no email or phone support contacts at Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not do anything, yet today (8 months after I asked this question) I noticed that **Tasks** reappeared in my list of calendars. I cannot explain it.

Answer (score 2):

When you expand "My Calendars" in the left-side bar, you should see "Tasks". Click on it to enable that calendar.

Also, go to Settings -> Calendar and see if Tasks is enabled.

Comment: As I stated in my question, **Tasks** is not in the list.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Do you see Tasks when you click on "GMail" in the GMail page (along with Contacts)? Also, when you add an entry in your calendar, do you get the option of choosing between an Event and a Task?

Comment: Also, go to Settings -> Calendar and see if Tasks is enabled.

Comment: Tasks work fine in Gmail. I do not have the option to add a task when I create a new event. When I go to **Settings** -> **Calendars** I do not see **Tasks** anywhere.

Comment: Huh. That's weird ...

Comment: The Reminders calendar replaced the tasks. Click the reminders drop down arrow and select "Switch to Tasks"

Answer (score 1):

Google replaced the Tasks calendar with Reminders. You can switch back by clicking the reminders drop down arrow and select "Switch to Tasks".

[image: image description]

Answer (score 0):

I made a new calendar called "tasks" at the settings list and it worked. instantly the tasks with due date from gmail synked with my "tasks" at the calendar.

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me either...

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to **change display language to English**, then you will see the 'tasks' calendar.

I had the same issue, tried this, and it worked.

[image]

Comment: It works if you change the language to English. It does not work if you use the language Swedish, for instance.

Comment: Didn't help me - I'm already on English

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's under 'My Calendars' by default but it does not appear in the Calendar view until it is specifically ticked.