# How do I get Google Tasks back on Google Calendar after “reminders” has replaced it?

Tags: google-calendar, google-tasks, google-calendar-reminders

Google offered me the possibility to to used Google reminders in my calendar, if I wanted.

I said, ok, let's try it.

Now Google Calendar has gone and there seems to be no way to get it back: [How do I get "Tasks" in my list of calendars?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37200/how-do-i-get-tasks-in-my-list-of-calendars)

Is there some kind of reset to basic I can do to remove the darn reminders or at least a method of getting reminders to sync with tasks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click on the drop down arrow next to Reminders in your calendar list. There should be an option to switch back to Google Tasks.